# Find the number of Kth-descendants of vertex v in tree

Tags: tree, binary-search, lowest-common-ancestor

The task is to find the number of kth-descendants of vertex v. I'm given the full tree of size n,n-1 vertices and q queries with the v and k. What is the fastest way to find the answer? I believe the solution is `O(N * log N)`,because max N,Q is = 500 000 and time limit is 2 sec. Here is example of input:

```
4
1 2
2 3
1 4
3
1 1
1 2
3 1
```

And output is:

```
2 1 0
```

I've tried using binary-lifting and `LCA` to find it, and I came up with idea to search at the depth of k + v.depth, and find such L and R that `LCA(L,R) = v` but it seems not to work properly.

//edit i've tried using binary-search to find min L and max R at depth k+ v.depth that LCA(L,R) = v

n is the number of vertices in a tree, n-1 is the number of edges between vertices(in input after n there is a and b and it means that in the tree there is a edge between vertex a and b), next we have a q which means a number of queries. In each query there is v and k,which stands for a vertex v for which we need to find answer and k is the level of descendant we are looking for. For example if k = 1 we are looking for a descendant of v, if k = 2 we are looking for 2-descendant of v(basically descendants descendant)(its hard to explain but its like our sons son = grandson).
Here is the whole code that i've tried. At some point my code outputs 0 instead of 2 and i'm not sure at which case.
https://gist.github.com/statkiewiczm/d3826bf8e4cd72ef5d7fb690d981ef5e
//final edit
I've solved the problem. The solution was to bin-search at the depth K + v.depth and L was the vertex with the lowest in.time > v in.time and R was the vertex with the highest out.time < v out.time.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can see where it went wrong? What is `n` and `v` and `k` in that input with just numbers? How does it define the tree?

Comment: i've added more information about the problem